# Python Tkinter error with button commands

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hi I was trying to make simple calculator using tkinter gui with python. 
But first of all I was trying to create buttons that once they are clicked, they were attached to the result shown on the screen. (Just as real-life calculator, if screen shows 12 and I click 3, the screen then shows 123)

```
from Tkinter import *
class Calculator(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title('Calculator')
        self.pack()

        self.screen=Frame(self, borderwidth=20, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.screen.pack()
        self.txtDisplay = Text(self.screen, width=20, height=2)
        self.txtDisplay.pack()
        self.screen.grid(row=0, columnspan=5) #columnspan to span multiple columns

        Contents = ['1','2','3','+','4','5','6','-','7','8','9','*','C','0','=','/']
        Buttons = [None]*16
        j=1
        count=0
        for i in range(16):
            Buttons[i]=Button(self, text=Contents[i], command=lambda : self.txtDisplay.insert(END, Contents[i]), height=2, width=5, borderwidth=5)
            Buttons[i].grid(row=j, column=i%4)
            count+=1
            if count%4==0:
                j+=1
                count=0


Calculator().mainloop()
```

However, the problem is the screen only attaches / whenever I click any button and eventually results in //////////////

[image]

/ is last element of Contents list and I guess there is something wrong with

```
command=lambda : self.txtDisplay.insert(END, Contents[i])
```

Can I get explanation on why this occurs and how I can deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very problem problem with `lambda` in `for` loop. You can find many answers.

`lambda` doesn't use value from `i` when you create button but when you press button - so all buttons use the same value `i` which directs to last button.

You have to assign `i` to argument in `lambda` and it will copy value from `i` when you create button

```
command=lambda x=i: self.txtDisplay.insert(END, Contents[x])
```

Comment: Oh i forgot I have to assign the each value. Thanks for helping !